# npm test does not detect new test file changes in jenkins

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jestjs

Jenkins/jest and CI ,

I have created a react APP using create-react-app and I use JEST for testing  and I did some new changes in a file created app.test.js and committed to git-hub- hooked it with jenkins -when I run npm test in the local machine the tests are run fine and they all pass .. 
BUT when i run the jenkins pipeline script it says the following :

```
No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
Press a to run all tests, or run Jest with --watchAll.

Watch Usage
› Press a to run all tests.
› Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
› Press q to quit watch mode.
› Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

I have tried changing app.test.js -created a new file commit changes and then created a new pipeline in jenkins and tried again ( I have also tried these discussed here :https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/930)  but I still get the above error : my pipeline script is shown below:

```
   node{
        stage "CI"    
        git 'https://github.com/NaveenDK/mentalshortcuts.git' 
        bat "npm install"  
        stage " Unit testing" 
        bat "npm test" 
    }
        def notify(status){
        emailext (
          to: "dd@dd.com",
          subject: "${status}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
          body: """<p>${status}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
            <p>Check console output at <a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a></p>""",
        )

    }

    node {
        notify("Deploy to staging?")
    }
    input 'Deploy to Staging?'


    node {
        bat "npm run-script build"
    }
```

Any help any links anything at all would be great!

Comment: Hi all I have tried the npm test command with a new app developed from scratch but still the problem exists...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tests did not run on jenkins as Jenkins was running on Windows, and Windows doesn't support glob, which is src/**/*.js.

this problem was not encountered when the project was build on Jenkins that was installed  on a Linux OS!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue. As mentioned above by Naveen, Windows doesn't support glob, which is src/**/*.js.
That's why in Jenkins configuration, change the label to Linux. Check here to see a preview.
[Jenkins configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5DzU.png)

And then in the build section, add the following line as shell commands:

```
npm install
npm run build
CI=true npm test
```

Always run `npm install` first. It will install all the packages.
Then run `npm run build` to build the app
In the end, make sure to write `CI=true npm test`. It will run test cases only once. If you write `npm test` instead, then it will run the test and go into watch mode forever.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as correct, it's very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem on my local machine like this,

```
"test": "jest --watchAll"
```